Dictionaries coming from JSON files
I am trying to understand the structure of a data coming from a json file ( not original GeoJSON) .
The data source is (https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/geojson.php)
After uploading the file I see it like this
[snapshot of a json file content in a vs code terminal][1]
After reading the file I examine its type
    filename = '1.0_month.json'
    with open (filename)as f:
        all_eq_data = json.load(f)
    print ( type(all_eq_data))

and it returns class <'dict'>
vs code shows all_eq_data as the consequence of dictionaries {} separated by comma:
{smth},{smth},{...},.....
snapshot of all_eq_data in the terminal
So, it doesn't look like typical structure of dictionaries {key:value}, it resembles a list of dictionaries: {key:value},{key:value}......
Moreover, if I ask
    all_eq_data.keys())
the IDE returns list of keys
dict_keys(['type', 'metadata', 'features', 'bbox']) that are keys of multiple dictionaries that all_eq_data is comprised of.
Then, I put
    all_eq_dicts = all_eq_data\['features'\]
and receive a class<list> of dictionaries there entries are the values of the 'feature' keys from all the dictionaries that are in all_eq_data.
Could you please explain the structure of this json file ( why it is considered to be a class<dict> while there are no key-value pairs in its structure?  Also, why when asking all_eq_dicts = all_eq_data['features']
I receive a list of a values from every dictionary in the all_eq_data dictionary, but not the single value as it usually happens with this kind of request to a dictionary object?     [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/V0NJlW9t.png   [2]: https://i.sstatic.net/f5tpiVF6.png

Please try to avoid post images, be clear with your question, JSON are not always dict

In my opinion, when you first read the data and get all_eq_data, it is the dictionary for all the data, with keys such as 'type', 'metadata', 'features', 'bbox' and so on. It does have the key-value pairs in this dictionary. The key-value pairs in this structure is like ('type', a string), ('metadata', a dictionary), ('bbox', a list), ('features', a list)...
So the value of a key not only could be a number, but also could be a string, a list, or a dictionary.
Take the key 'features' as example: when you use all_eq_data['features'] to get all_eq_dicts, the all_eq_dicts is actually the value of the key 'features', which is a list.
You can also try on some other keys to get to understand that. For example, all_eq_data['type'] would receive a class string, all_eq_data['metadata'] would receive a class dictionary...
